# index.js not loading from main.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a .net core MVC application. where I have integrated Twilio Video functionality.
In Views/Video/index.cshtml, reference for require js added like this,

```
<script data-main="../TwilioVideo/main" src="~/TwilioVideo/require.js"></script>
```

folder structure is like,

- `wwwroot`

  - `TwilioVideo`

    - `index.js`
    - `main.js`
    - `require.js`

and the main.js file contains code,

```
    require.config({
paths: {
    "twilio-video": "https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.4.0/twilio-video.min"
}
});
require(["index"], function () {

});
```

when I run the code index file not loading, in the source I can only see main.js and require.js. someone, please help me to understand what might be the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use code like this:

```
require.config({
            paths: {
                "twilio-video": "/TwilioVideo"//It's the path of TwilioVideo folder
            }
        })
        require(["twilio-video/index"], function () {

        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! tried this but not working on production

see screenshot, [link] (https://prnt.sc/26qflu1)

Comment: Can you share your Console?

Comment: Console (https://prnt.sc/26ucozg)